# dom elements click fires each time when Jquery initialization function triggers

Tags: jquery, onclick, datatables-1.10

Used the Jquery Datatable to retrieve data by using ajax. And also using the inline table edit plugin with that datatable to initialize the inline edit function. Problem is once click the save button to done the update in inline edit, reload the datatable for get the dynamic data, when reload the table we trigger the inline edit function again for to get the inline functionality in the table, otherwise inline function not working in the datatable. After that inline table initialization, click the save button it fires two times. Each time of initialization the save button click event fires each time. Here my code,

Initialize datatable once complete ajax, initialize inline table.

```
function purchase_payments_table(id) {
var i = 1;
pay_trans_table = $('#pay_trans_table').DataTable({
    searching: false,
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    ordering: false,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "No transaction for this bill"
    },
    // ajax: get_purchase_payments + '/' + id,
    "ajax": {
        "url": get_purchase_payments + '/' + id,
        dataSrc: function(data) {
            records_total = data.recordsTotal;
            return data.data;
        },
        complete: function() {
            init_tabeledit();
            i = 1;
            if (records_total != 0) {
                $('.tabledit-toolbar-column').css("display", "table-cell");
                $('.tabledit-toolbar').css("display", "block");
            } else {
                $('.tabledit-toolbar-column').css("display", "none");
                $('.tabledit-toolbar').css("display", "none");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            custom_err(jqXHR, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    },
    columns: [{
            data: 'id',
            name: 'id',
            className: 'hide_column'
        },
        {
            render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
            }
        },
        {
            data: 'created_at',
            name: 'created_at',
            render: function(data, type, row) {
                return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            }
        },
        {
            data: 'paid_amt',
            name: 'paid_amt'
        },
        {
            data: 'adj_amt',
            name: 'adj_amt'
        },
    ],
    responsive: true,
    initComplete: function() {
        $("#pay_trans_table").show();
        // init_tabeledit();
    }
});}
```

Function for inline table,

```
function init_tabeledit() {
$('#pay_trans_table').Tabledit({
    url: update_purchase_payments,
    dataType: "json",
    columns: {
        identifier: [0, 'id'],
        editable: [
            [3, 'paid_amt'],
            [4, 'adj_amt']
        ]
    },
    restoreButton: false,
    onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.action == 'edit') {
            $(".tabledit-delete-button").css("display", "block");

            $('.tabledit-edit-button').each(function() {
                $(this).children("span").remove();
                $(this).append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>');
            });
            // pay_trans_table.ajax.reload();
            // bills_table.ajax.reload();
            success_notify();
        }
        if (data.action == 'delete') {
            $('#' + data.id).remove();
            // pay_trans_table.ajax.reload();
            // bills_table.ajax.reload();
            danger_notify();
        }
        pay_trans_table.ajax.reload();
        bills_table.ajax.reload();
        var bill_id = $('#bill_id').val();
        fetchpaymnt_on_focout(bill_id);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        custom_err(jqXHR, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});}
```

Save event code from plugin js,

```
i.on("click", "button.tabledit-save-button", function(e) {
        console.log('test');
        e.handled !== !0 && (e.preventDefault(), b.submit(t(this).parents("tr").find("td.tabledit-edit-mode")), e.handled = !0)
    })) : (i.on(d.eventType, "tr:not(.tabledit-deleted-row) td.tabledit-view-mode", function(t) {
        t.handled !== !0 && (t.preventDefault(), b.reset(i.find("td.tabledit-edit-mode")), u.edit(this), t.handled = !0)
    })
```

Comment: https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/  this plugin used for the inline editing.

Comment: e.stopImmediatePropagation(); helps me in the plugin js code. :)